# Update or SaveorUpdate in CRUDRespository, Is there any options available

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to do CRUD operations with My Entity bean. `CRUDRepository` provide standard methods to `find`, `delete` and `save` but there is no generic method available like `saveOrUpdate(Entity entity)` that in turn calls `Hibernate` or `HibernateTemplate` sessions `saveorUpdate()` methods.

The way `CRUDRepository` provides this functionality is to 
use like this

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Space c SET c.owner = :name WHERE c.id = :id")
Integer setNameForId(@Param("name") String name, @Param("id")
```

but this is not generic and needs to be written for complete form fields.
Please let me know if there is any way or i can get session of Hibernate or object of Spring HibernateTemplate to solve this issue.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The implementation of the method

`<S extends T> S save(S entity)`

from interface

`CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID>`

automatically does what you want. If the entity is new it will call `persist` on the `entity manager`, otherwise it will call `merge`

The code looks like this:

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

and can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L505). Note that `SimpleJpaRepository` is the class that automatically implements `CrudRepository` in Spring Data JPA.

Therefore, there is no need to supply a custom `saveOrUpdate()` method. Spring Data JPA has you covered.

Comment: Hi,You are correct. i got the issue now, i am using thymeleaf UI template and The Bean that i am trying to persist that is Form bean not Entity bean and that's why Spring boot is not saving it. Now i have to convert the entire Form bean into Entity bean with changed values and try to persist it.

Comment: Why would I exactly put this if I'm already extending the CrudRepository? Would this is an @Override method within the interface DAO?

Comment: @user1342086 That's the point, you don't add this since the functionality is already there

Comment: @geoand Ok thanks. I get it for saveOrUpdate() but what about update()? I tried looking at the CrudRepository.class but I couldn't find one. So in the case where I have a Java object and I want to search the DB to see if that object exists (not by the ID but by the other columns), how would one go about doing that?

Comment: @You would add a method to your interface, for example findByName, and Sprig Data would create it automatically. The reference documentation has plenty of examples

Comment: Great to know they got us covered. You know what would be even greater? If there were ANY documentation available.

Comment: @Blauhirn Due to the size and multitude of features, the documentation of the various Spring projects can at times be hard to navigate

Comment: @kittu you should probably create a question that contains the specific details of your use case.

Comment: NOT:This answer doesn't meet the requirement in the question if you do @Async operations.So Modifying and Query  annotations will be better for Async operations

Answer (score -3):

The issue is "i am using thymeleaf UI template and The Bean that i am trying to persist that is Form bean not Entity bean and that's why Spring boot is not saving it. Now i have to convert the entire Form bean into Entity bean with changed values and try to persist it." I got the solution for the specific problem i faced in my project, The solution is use @ModelAttribute to convert the form bean to entity.

```
@ModelAttribute("spaceSummary")
public SpaceSummary getSpaceSummary(int id){
    return this.spaceSummaryService.getSpaceSummary(id);
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mgr/editSpace", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editSpace(@ModelAttribute("spaceSummary") SpaceSummary                
spaceSummary, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect, ModelAndView model) {

}
```