# Spring Hibernate - FindByObject CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is it possible (if so, how) would one add custom methods in the CrudRepository interface?

I have the following DAO with a entity class called, Foobar. For the sake of this question - the entity class can have any number of fields/columns.

```
package com.bar
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.bar.Foobar
public interface FoobarCrudRepo extends CrudRepository<Foobar, Long> {
    public Foobar findByObject(Foobar JObj);
}
```

This code works fine if you remove that custom method but throws an error if I add it (like above). My understanding from this post ([Update or SaveorUpdate in CRUDRespository, Is there any options available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420572/update-or-saveorupdate-in-crudrespository-is-there-any-options-available/24423508?noredirect=1#comment69306080_24423508)) was that I just needed to add an additional method to the interface (as shown in the example) and the JPARepo will take care of the rest. However, I'm getting the error below. My thinking - it doesn't know much about this custom class.

Here's my error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Foobar': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property object found for type Foobar!
```

Why would I want a findbyObject() you might ask? So that I don't insert duplicate rows of data into the DB by checking the DB to see if the object has already been added and performing a check.

Any suggestions would help, thanks.

Comment: You're wanting to check if the object exists in the Database by using the entire object as the key?  Why not have a unique ID?

Comment: Not as a key but as a object. To my understanding, the uniqueID is being generated once it's being inserted into the DB and not before. That said, how would I be able to find the uniqueID before inserting it?

Comment: To do what you want to do, you would almost just have to pick just the fields that need to be unique for the object to be unique and check those against what is in the DB currently.

Comment: After searching the internet for a while now, I agree with you and jWest. It sounds almost like a "constructor" (not exactly) being placed here. Could an alternative be placing an if-statement within a service layer class which calls this DAO?

Comment: what does this have to do with hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindByObject` doesn't look for an object, it literally looks for a field in your `Foobar` class named `Object`. Like others have mentioned, you can check other fields of the object to see if it already exists.

For example, if your `Foobar` class has `String name` and `String email` fields, you could create a method like `public Foobar findByNameAndEmail(String name, String email) {}`, and this would return a Foobar object if there was a record in the database that met these criteria.

All query methods do is replicate SQL, so ask yourself, could you "find by object (record)" in SQL? No, because that makes no sense. Your query would return a record (object) WHERE certain conditions are met.

Comment: It's surprising that Hibernate doesn't think about this scenario - for a simple example, say employee and department with a M:1 relationship. In SQL, you'd insert information about employees on one and the department on the other. On the employees table, you can have multiple employees belonging to the same department by sharing the FK departmentID. That way, you can reuse rows within the department table.

Comment: You can do what you're talking about in Hibernate, using the `@ManyToOne` annotation. I would suggest learning more about Hibernate, because it's pretty flexible and fairly straightforward to do everything you would be able to in fully typed out SQL.

Comment: I am still trying to learn hibernate but it still adds duplicate rows, even with the @ManyToOne annotation

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because it takes the Names behind findBy and tries to create the where condition with that.

So findByObject creates:

```
where object = ?
```

to find the object by id you can call

```
findOne(?)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the findOne() must take in a param ID matching the data type (in this case, it'd be Long). Since I'm searching by an object, it's not valid.

Comment: Sure but you have the object can get the Id and pass this as argument. I don't see the problem

Comment: I don't have the ID - it gets created on insertion and I have the object prior to that.

Comment: so what should findByObject then do? Find it on all other fields? Do you have a unique field in that object?

Comment: Exactly, it seems like the best way would be to by all of the fields that the object has. So in SQL, it'd be something like: select [whatever] form table where fieldA=? and fieldB=? and so on. I can't assume that I have a unique field in these objects but the point is the reduce the amount of duplicates anyways.

Comment: Then you have to create a method with all fields you need like J.West suggested