# Why doesn't JpaRepository update my entity?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have such Jpa repository:

```
public interface BalanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Balance, Long> {

}
```

As far as I know (and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423508/1315357) it confirms) entity manager insert new record (when entity is new) and update entity record when is not new.

My entity class hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "balances")
public class Balance extends BaseEntity {
// omitted 
}
```

and `BaseEntity`

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    public abstract class BaseEntity {

        private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(BaseEntity.class);

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private Long id;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
               this.id = id;
            }

    public boolean isNew() {
            return id == null;
        }

 }
```

When I save new `Balance` entity, new record is inserted but not update is done, why?

```
Balance bal = new Balance();
        bal.setFinalBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
        bal.setUser(user);
        bal.setRecordDate(date);
        bal.setMinusBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
        bal.setPlusBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
        bal.setTotalBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);

        // entity is inserted
        balanceRepository.save(bal);

        // no update...
        bal.setFinalBalance(bal.getFinalBalance().add(BigDecimal.TEN));
        balanceRepository.save(bal);
```

---

**Update 1** - When I `findOne(Long id)` updated record, value seems to be updated, but value in database is not changed.

Comment: Is there really no update in the database? Merge operation will not update the entity you passed, but will return a new one

Comment: Really, no update in database table... (I write out queries with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`)

Comment: have you tried to do an entityMananger.flush() after your update? JPA caches database requests and just flushes them later (after the transaction ends)... that is no problem as long as you are working with jpa on a single node/application...

Comment: No, I haven't. Is it really needed? I think it should work automatically.

Comment: You are most likely missing `@Transactional` annotation

Comment: Do you mean `@Transaction` from Spring or `javax.transaction` ?

Comment: Isn't it connected to `equals()` and `hashcode()`? How does EM knows that record has been modified and should update it?

Comment: It shouldn't be - unless you tell it through some fancy annotation to check it should just invoke an update with all fields, regardless of whether there were changes or not. Flushing didn't work? What happens when you try to retrieve that object from database in your code? Is it updated or not?

Comment: Yes, when I `findOne(Long id)` the updated record after update, value is updated. But no physical modification in database.

Comment: So it has to be caching issue, you updated it in the Persistence Context. Either EntityManager doesn't flush for some reason (your functions end correctly right, you do not stay in an infinite loop in a transaction or something?), or you have second level cache configured or.... something...

Comment: No, there is only Service layer that save entity into repository. No cache, no loop, API request is done.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Make sure to update your question with information of what you tried so that it's better visible.

Comment: @Deltharis Thanks! :)

Comment: In short, nobody has any idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Artegon Did you able to resolve that issue, as I am facing the issue

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "bal = balanceRepository.save(bal);" ... this will return the saved object and will include the generated id ... when you run the next save, it will know that it is an existing object and will then do an update instead of a save.

If that doesn't work, create a newBalance object, set it on the first save and use it for the second save and setFinalBalance call.

Comment: EntityManager.persist (which will get called on first save) does update the object you pass to it - so `bal` does have the generated id.

Comment: Yeah ... I didn't think about that. My bad. 8-{

I normally use CrudRepository from Spring Boot ... so my JPA Repository is a little rusty ... ignore my answer. 8-}

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your code such way:

```
@Service
public class BalanceService {
  // ...
  @Transactional
  public void save(Balance balance){
     balanceRepository.save(balance);  
  }

  public void check(){
     Balance bal = new Balance();
    bal.setFinalBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
    bal.setUser(user);
    bal.setRecordDate(date);
    bal.setMinusBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
    bal.setPlusBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
    bal.setTotalBalance(BigDecimal.TEN);
    // entity is inserted
    save(bal);

    bal.setFinalBalance(bal.getFinalBalance().add(BigDecimal.TEN));
    save(bal);

  }

}
```

And tell me does it help or not.

Comment: `@Transactional` from javax or from Spring?

Comment: Which wouldn't make any difference... Spring uses proxies and internal method calls don't pass through the proxy. Hence `@Transactional` is basically ignored here.

Comment: Sorry @rvit34, no change. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hei

This part looks weird to me:

```
public boolean isNew() {
    return id == null;
}
```

Because this function is covered by the `Persistable` interface and is the default implementation. Read here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites

You can override this function by implementing the `Persistable` interface in your `Entity`. I needed to do this because I used an not gerenerated table id as PK.

Do you try to save the data during a `@DataJpaTest`? Because this can lead to open transactions and will not save to the database.

Is the return value from `balanceRepository.save(bal);` the same as `bal`? If not you can trie to add the `@Version` annotation. I read that this sometimes might help.
You can also trie to implement the `Persistable` interface and add the `@Version` annotation and use it like this:

```
@Version
private Long version;

@Override
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public boolean isNew() {
    return version == null;
}
```