# How can I implement a Save Or Update function using Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, relational-database

I am using Spring Data JPA to save a record to my database.
Here is the method I am using:

```
@Override
public void persistOrder(final Order order) {
    orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

and my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    Optional<Order> findByOrderId(UUID orderId);
}
```

I want to modify this so it will Save or Update. This is what I have so far:

```
@Override
public void saveOrUdpate(final Order order) {
  orderRepository.save(order);
  long id = orderRepository.findByOrderId(order.get()).getId();
  orderRepository.deleteById(id);
  orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

I have a few questions - 
#1 Is this bad practice (deleting and then re-inserting)? 
#2 If I implement my repo using hibernate, would a hibernate saveOrUpdate(..) do the same thing under the hood? 
#3 Do you have an idea how I can achieve this just using plain Spring Data Jpa? 

Thanks :)

Comment: 1. Definitely yes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420572/update-or-saveorupdate-in-crudrespository-is-there-any-options-available .

Comment: Thanks I saw that, but how do I use it to update multiple columns?

Comment: @JohnnyAlpha Multiple columns or multiple rows? Colums should work out of the box. Just change your object and save it, all colums should be updated. For multiple rows there should be a saveAll method in JpaRepository.

Comment: You can fetch existing data by id then map your existing data with new data then save. You can use ModelMapper to map models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update::
Ok, thanks for the comments, I've decided to add a separate update method! I think this is looking better!

```
 @Override
 public void updateOrder(Order order) {
    long id = orderRepository.findByOrderId(order.get().getId());
    order.setId(id);
    orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

A good point was made about Spring Data JPA's save(..) method doing an upsert by default. But, unfortunately in the project I'm working on the primary keys are autogenerated. This means that whenever save(..) is executed on an existing record to update it, a new record is created instead! That's why I explicitly set the id here to avoid that happening!
I've also added and eclipse-link library @Index annotation to the orderId column (not primary key) in the entity class to speed up the update method's findByOrderId!

Comment: Actually, you could annotate your update method with ‘@Transactional’ and let spring manage all transaction flow. Also you will not need to call ‘orderRepository.save()’, because spring will care about save your entity. And one thing more. Maybe you don’t need to set ID of persisting object to your patch object? You could just check - is field of entity updated or not and set field to entity from DB if that field was updated.