# Spring Data update Entity is erasing fields non declared in the request

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I'm trying to develop a CRUD for an application, having the following model:

```
@Entity
public Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private String email;
}
```

and the following mapping for the update:

```
@PatchMapping(value = "/update/{id}", consumes = "application/json")
public Person updatePerson(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Person payload){
      return personRepository.save(payload);
    }
```

If I have an object created as:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe"
}
```

Doing an update request as:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alfred"
}
```

will erase all the other fields not defined on the request. Is there a "clever" way to update that I'm failing to notice or I have to check field by field if they are set and update them accordingly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update an entity using spring-data-jpa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881479/how-do-i-update-an-entity-using-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Hi, did you have an answer since?