# Are transactions possible without @Version annotion

Tags: mongodb, jpa, transactions, datanucleus

I am using datanucleus with mongodb and JPA. Is it possible to ensure transactions on individual entities that don't have an @Version annotation? For smaller entities, it seems like it would not be unreasonable to simply compare the entire entity to see if it has changed, but I'm not 100% clear [if this is implemented in DN/Mongo](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/transaction_types.html).

Related question: [Java - JPA - @Version annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572566/java-jpa-version-annotation)

Comment: @Version is simply an annotation to say how to compare versions (if not specified then there is no check). A transaction happens anyway, and that is only whether a check is performed just before commit on the connection. So no idea what you're referring to being implemented or not

Comment: Arg, I'm an idiot. I meant *locking* not *transactions*. Sorry for the confusion -- you've answered my question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i don't know the mondo driver, but have built entities with and without @Version, maybe a hint will help a bit: 
@Version is needed for optimistic locking. if no @Version field is contained in your beans you have to use pessimistic locking, because you can not detect concurrent changes.
regards from germany,
Thomas