# How does spring data rest send the version and the id of a document to the REST API client?

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

We are using mongodb and spring data rest in a spring boot app. We expose the documents via spring data rest default REST API. For optimistic locking each document is annotated with `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Version` and `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id`.

I wonder how these attributes are exposed by default through the REST API so that the client can update a document.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780621/does-spring-data-rest-support-jpa-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding id:**
spring-data-rest hides the id by default and tries to communicate only with links to resources. It tries to apply the principles of HATEAOS - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional.etag

**Regarding version:**
If you have a version specified in your entity (I only have spring-data-jdbc background) spring-data-rest will report the version in the response in the ETag Header.

If you e.g. issue a patch and want to make sure the version you update is still up-to-date with what your read before you can use the `ETag` you received in the `If-Match` header. If the version is no longer up-to-date you receive a `412 Precondition Failed`

So here is my request flow:

```
//get a product
http :8080/products/2 -v

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "2"
```

The patch request would look like this

```
http PATCH :8080/products/2 name=some3 If-Match:2 -v
Request:
  PATCH /products/2 HTTP/1.1
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json
  If-Match: 1
Response:
  HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
  ETag: "3"
```

You will find details in the spring-data-rest documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional.etag