# JPA increase the value of a column by one

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement a DAO that increases the value of the "version" column automatically. The version is not a primay key. The problem is that I tried the "@GeneratedValue" value before, but it didnt work and sql was giving a message *this is only allowed for a primarykey columns*, so I had to use the lastUpdate value and increase it one value, but this doesn't work and it keeps passing 1 for the insert value.

here is my code :

```
@Repository
public class VersionDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create(Version version) {
        Version lastUpdate = (Version) em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Version c ORDER BY c.uploadedtimestamp DESC")//
        .setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
        int ver = lastUpdate.getVersion() + 1;
        version.setVersion(ver);

        em.persist(version);
    }

    public void delete(Version version) {
        em.remove(version);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "version")
public class Version implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name = "version")   
    private Integer version;

    @Column(name="uploadedtimestamp")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date uploadedtimestamp = new Date();        

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Version cdi = (Version) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(getId(), cdi.getId()).isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).append(getId()).toHashCode();
    }

    public Date getUploadedtimestamp() {
        return uploadedtimestamp;
    }

    public void setUploadedtimestamp(Date uploadedtimestamp) {
        this.uploadedtimestamp = uploadedtimestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not clear what you want. Is it somethig like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572566/java-jpa-version-annotation]. A version when updating an entity?

Comment: no the version name is for something else. I just want to add its value by one, everytime there is a new insert

Comment: Are you trying to update a field called version or you are trying to create a new object with an incremented version

Comment: I just want to update the field called version

Comment: @user261002 which DBMS are you using? Mysql, SQL Server, what else?

Comment: Sounds like a trigger for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JPA 2.0 there is the `@Version` annotation.

You just need to add the annotation to the field you want to be your version field, like that:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    //...
}
```

Take a look at: [Java - JPA - @Version annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572566/java-jpa-version-annotation)

Answer (score 1):

try to select max version, and update the value + 1.

```
public void incrementVersion() {
        Version lastUpdate = (Version) em.createQuery("SELECT max (c.version) FROM X c")          .setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
        int ver = lastUpdate.getVersion() + 1;
        lastUpdate.setVersion(ver);

        em.persist(lastUpdate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't handle this via JPA. You can create a trigger for your table to automatically increase "version" value every time a row is updated.

If you're using MySQL for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER version_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON `your_table`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.version = (OLD.version + 1)
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer as it does not use JPA as the OP asked and kinda breaks the concept of jpa database agnosticism