# How to update the JPA/Hibernate @Version field in a Spring Data JPA @Modifying @Query query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For **testing the @Version annotation**, I am using the following setup to manage persistence:

- Spring Boot Starter 1.5.3.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.2.10.Final
- Spring Data Envers 1.1.3.RELEASE -> Spring Data JPA 1.11.3.RELEASE

Databases tested:

- H2
- PostgreSQL
- MariaDB
- Oracle

The entities are utilizing an @Version annotated field which will be [incremented on update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2572633/4635513). One example entity looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"users\"")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private boolean active;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long version = 0L;

    // getters/setters (not shown)

}
```

The **Spring Data JPA based UserRepository provides custom modifying queries** besides the CRUD ones:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.active = false WHERE u.id = ?1")
    void deactivate(Long id);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.active = false WHERE u.id IN :ids")
    void deactivateAll(@Param("ids") Long... ids);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.active = false WHERE u.id IN :ids")
    void deactivateAll(@Param("ids") Iterable<Long> ids);

}
```

As the *version field is not automatically increased for JPQL/HQL queries*, this *must be done manually* by adjusting the custom queries accordingly.

When **trying to use the Hibernate specific** (non-JPA conforming) **VERSIONED** keyword (HQL only) to extend the query

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE VERSIONED User u SET u.active = false WHERE u.id = ?1")
void deactivate(Long id);
```

the **generated SQL is not valid** indepentently of the database tested, **resulting in an error** looking something like this (schema name is TEST):

> Table "USER0_" not found; SQL statement: update "TEST"."users" set
>   user0_."version"=user0_."version"+1, "active"=0 where ("id") IN
>   (select "id" from "HT_users") [42102-194]

**So, how can I update the JPA/Hibernate @Version field in a Spring Data JPA @Modifying @Query query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **add** `u.version=u.version+1` **to the query**. The updated `@Query`s look like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.version=u.version+1, u.active = false WHERE u.id = ?1")
    void deactivate(Long id);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.version=u.version+1, u.active = false WHERE u.id IN :ids")
    void deactivateAll(@Param("ids") Long... ids);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.version=u.version+1, u.active = false WHERE u.id IN :ids")
    void deactivateAll(@Param("ids") Iterable<Long> ids);

}
```

**There may be caveats using this.** E.g. this will *obviously not fail with an* `OptimisticLockException` like updates issued by the EntityManager do ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2572633/4635513)).

Comment: Try to use `@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)` instead of incrementing version manually

Comment: @JaySmith Thank you very much for the hint, but it seems to me that the Lock annotation cannot be combined with a modifying query like the ones from my example repository. At least I get a pretty self-speaking exception: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to set lock mode on a non-SELECT query" when simply adding it as is. The documentation and API docs do not help me here or I'm missing something. Do I have to take anything else into account?

Comment: I created hql query with `versioned` keyword and it works ok. You get error `Table "USER0_"` not found` . Is it related to `versioned` keyword? In [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic-version-number) it is said that you cannot modify `version` explicitly.

Comment: @JaySmith did you use Query annotation for the HQL? What about the JPA settings, e.g. globally quoted identifiers. I will update my question and add some of my missing settings. And you're right, the hibernate docs say it is forbidden to alter the version manually. I will take a look at the Lock annotation again, maybe I'll find a hint there what to do to update the version properly. Actually that's why I asked the question as it is not obvious to me so far. Thanks again for your support!

Comment: I didn't use spring data jpa. I created hql query with `session.createQuery` method.

Comment: @JaySmith Ok, thank you for the update. I had no time to investigate further on the `VERSIONED` keyword. About the Lock annotation, I asked another SO question to clarify if this is possible at all or not, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896128/

Answer (score 0):

As answered the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47814583/5559599) - try to add VERSIONED keyword after the UPDATE keyword:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE VERSIONED User...)
```